# How to report ModelNotFoundException with stacktrace to Sentry.io in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, sentry

I am using below laravel 6 code to report exceptions to Sentry.io:

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if ($this->shouldReport($exception) && app()->bound('sentry')) {
        app('sentry')->captureException($exception);
    }

    parent::report($exception);
}
```

All the exceptions are able to report to sentry. However recently I found that  **ModelNotFoundException**  is not sending to Sentry. Also I found the reason and it is due to the presence of ModelNotFoundException in the below code of the file (***Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php***):

```
protected $internalDontReport = [
        AuthenticationException::class,
        AuthorizationException::class,
        HttpException::class,
        HttpResponseException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        SuspiciousOperationException::class,
        TokenMismatchException::class,
        ValidationException::class,
    ];
```

As inbuilt code and I cannot remove ModelNotFoundException in the above code.
Is there a way to send the ModelNotFoundException to sentry?

Answer (score 0):

The `$internalDontReport` is protected so you could override it, although it's probably better not too since the list might change in the future and would require you to keep it in sync.

You can remove the `$this->shouldReport($exception)`, however this will cause *all* of those ignored exception to be reported which might not be what you want.

You could do something like this in case you only care about the `ModelNotFoundException`:

```php
    protected $doReportToSentry = [
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
    ];

    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        if ($this->shouldReportToSentry($e) && app()->bound('sentry')) {
            app('sentry')->captureException($e);
        }

        parent::report($e);
    }

    protected function shouldReportToSentry(Exception $e)
    {
        if ($this->shouldReport($e)) {
            return true;
        }

        return !is_null(\Illuminate\Support\Arr::first($this->doReportToSentry, function ($type) use ($e) {
            return $e instanceof $type;
        }));
    }
```

You can add to that `$doReportToSentry` array any class you want to make sure it is reported even though Laravel might (by default) ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem myself where `findOrFail` was return 404 responses when a model that should always exist is not found. I wanted it to return a 500 and log it instead so I can be aware of the database inconsistency.

My solution was to override a couple of methods in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` like so:

```
protected function shouldntReport(Throwable $e): bool
{
    $shouldntReport = parent::shouldntReport($e);

    return $e instanceof ModelNotFoundException ? false : $shouldntReport;
}

protected function prepareException(Throwable $e): Throwable
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return $e;
    }

    return parent::prepareException($e);
}
```

The first override `shouldntReport` causes the error to be written to the log.

The second override `prepareException` causes a 500 error to be returned instead of a 404.

If you're fine with a 404 error and just want it logged (and sent to Sentry), feel free to only override the first method.

Keep in mind that if you do this you will need to check if models exist and return 404s manually when you need to. But this will avoid, for example, the problem of a missing subentity returning a 404 and making it look like the root entity is missing.

For example if you expect all users to have a relationship to a role model, and one user doesn't have a role, my changes make it so that Laravel doesn't return a 404 error. This is a database inconsistency and should be a 500 error. A 404 error would make it look like the user wasn't found, which is false. It's the role, not the user, that wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new I wasn't able to comment on @Chris answer.

I'm using Laravel 10.

Since class ModelNotFoundException extends RecordsNotFoundException I had to make this change

```
protected function prepareException(Throwable $e): Throwable
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return $e;
    }

    if ($e instanceof RecordsNotFoundException) {
        return $e;
    }

    return parent::prepareException($e);
}
```